# can't stop docker couchbase-community

Tags: docker, couchbase, docker-container

I started couchbase community with docker as following:

`docker run -e CB_RAMSIZE=256 -e "CB_ADMIN_PWD=123456" --name couchbase-community -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 crobin/couchbase-community`

I'm now trying to stop it with

```
docker stop couchbase-community
docker kill couchbase-community
docker kill -s 9 couchbase-community
```

Nothing stops it.

It's just stuck alive.  Anyway for me to stop that container?!

the result of `docker ps -a`

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                                                                               NAMES
9deed40a7db9        crobin/couchbase-community   "bash /bin/start-cb.…"   32 hours ago        Up 32 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8091-8094->8091-8094/tcp, 11207/tcp, 11211/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11210->11210/tcp, 18091-18094/tcp   couchbase-community
7b265619e593        nginx                        "--name nginx"           8 weeks ago         Created                 80/tcp                                                                                              laughing_brahmagupta
65f7ebdf03ba        nginx                        "1000"                   8 weeks ago         Created                 80/tcp                                                                                              lucid_heyrovsky
e402edffeeaa        db148b62d457                 "tini -- start-noteb…"   2 months ago        Created                                                                                                                     admiring_brattain
60e58a104b52        db148b62d457                 "tini -- start-noteb…"   2 months ago        Created                                                                                                                     eloquent_elion
a668f900566e        db148b62d457                 "tini -- start-noteb…"   2 months ago        Created                                                                                                                     unruffled_poitras
6fe2e4bd18bc        jupyterhub/jupyterhub        "--generate-config"      2 months ago        Created                 8000/tcp
```

docker and OS version

> docker Version 17.12.0-ce-mac55 (23011) on macbook 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

[image]

Comment: What docker version do you use? I don't see any problem to stop above container on ubuntu 16.04 with docker version `17.12.1-ce`.

Comment: Would you please post the information you see when you use `docker ps -a`?

Comment: @Nickolay docker Version 17.12.0-ce-mac55 (23011) on macbook 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: @MatthewGroves adding the result of ps -a to the question

Comment: what about `docker stop 9deed40a7db9`?

Comment: @meatspace still stuck uploaded moving gif of it to the question.

Comment: Try `sudo docker update --restart=no couchbase-community` then `docker stop couchbase-community`

Comment: @Jas let me know if `sudo docker update --restart=no couchbase-community` and `docker stop couchbase-community` worked.

Comment: @200OK I tried the above both `sudo docker update --restart=no couchbase-community` and `docker stop couchbase-community` and are stuck.

Comment: is it possible to kill the process directly without docker?

Comment: tbh the way this image is handling exit signals is hacky, not sure why the script needs to be so complex (see [here](https://github.com/christopherobin/docker-couchbase/blob/master/setup.sh)). Its not docker, its the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like your docker daemon is stuck or this specific container/something broke it.

Firstly if you restart your docker demon/Docker for Mac (using its panel) container will be stopped regardless, as engine that runs on it will go down.

Then either, if you do not care about it's data stored in volume you can just remove it via `docker rm -f 9deed40a7db9` , or just restart it.

I would reccomend doing `docker system prune && docker volume prune` if you do not care about volumes/unused images/containers you have on your machine and to check what image you using does in its Dockerfile and what volumes it introduces to the docker engine.

Comment: thanks, restarting docker daemon/docker for mac did the trick, wasn't aware of `prune` options, looks interesting, any best practices for using it would be appreciated.